# Как сделать синий... колонтитул в LaTeX?

Tags: latex

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать такие же синие фигуры в техе, как представлено на изображении. Каким образом можно добиться такого результата?(на второй картинке синий квадрат внизу страницы)

Comment: Какой класс документа и какая геометрия страницы? По куску картинки - это не похоже на обычный article.

Comment: Так же советуую ознакомиться - https://tex.stackexchange.com/ . Возможно, там есть ответ на Ваш вопрос